# Pivot-Like Table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've created a pivot like table using dplyr within dcast. Just curious if there is a better more efficient way to do this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

state.x77 <- as.data.frame(state.x77)

state.x77$Population_bucket <- ifelse(state.x77$Population >=
10000,'Large',ifelse(state.x77$Population >= 1000,'Medium',"Small"))
state.x77$Income_bucket <- ifelse(state.x77$Income >=
4700,'High',ifelse(state.x77$Income >= 4100,'Medium',"Low"))

dcast(state.x77 %>% 
group_by(Income_bucket, Population_bucket) %>% 
summarise(sum(Area)),
Income_bucket ~ Population_bucket)
```

Comment: `with(state.x77, tapply(Area, list(Income_bucket, Population_bucket), sum))` which part are you not happy with, the dcast?

Comment: Just seeing if there is a more efficient way to do it. I want to make this a function. Can you be of assistance?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to create tables like this in R and `dcast` is a fine one. In terms of coding, you can use the `cut` function instead of `ifelse` to create the grouping columns, and the grouping can be done within a `dplyr` chain. Also, it might be more clear to invoke `dcast` at the end of the chain, rather than including the chain inside `dcast`. For example:

```
labs = c("Small","Medium","Large")

state.x77 %>% 
  group_by(Population_bucket = cut(Population, breaks=c(0, 1000, 10000, Inf), 
                                   labels= labs, right=FALSE),
           Income_bucket = cut(Income, breaks=c(0, 4100, 4700, Inf), 
                               labels=labs, right=FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(sum(Area)) %>%
  dcast(Income_bucket ~ Population_bucket)
```

> ```
>   Income_bucket  Small Medium  Large
> 1         Small   9267 740233     NA
> 2        Medium 411498 662657 348075
> 3         Large 754001 351123 259940
> ```

If you want to create an output table to be read by humans, you can also format the values, say, with a thousands separator. In that case, the `summarise` line would change to the following:

```
summarise(format(sum(Area), big.mark=",")) %>%
```

And the output would be:

> ```
>   Income_bucket   Small  Medium   Large
> 1         Small   9,267 740,233    <NA>
> 2        Medium 411,498 662,657 348,075
> 3         Large 754,001 351,123 259,940
> ```